# ImportError: No module named Cython.Distutils (But there is)

Tags: python, cython, kivy, importerror, buildozer

I have Cython 0.20 installed, and can do 'from Cython.Distutils import build_ext' from a python interpreter, so I don't understand
the below error, when I am trying to build an apk with buildozer. My log_level in buildozer.spec is set to 2 already. It appears to be trying to install jnius into a virtualenv(unless i'm mistaken).. I assume this is normal, as I haven't set up any myself. Any suggestions? I've googled around to no avail. My OS is Ubuntu 15.04.

The following is the tail end of the output from the command:

```
buildozer --verbose android debug deploy run
```

..

```
 # Install distribute
    # Run 'curl http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py | venv/bin/python'
    # Cwd /home/yerman/PycharmProjects/genius/.buildozer
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
      0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:16 --:--:--     0
    # Install requirement jnius in virtualenv
    # Run 'pip install --download-cache=/home/yerman/.buildozer/cache --target=/home/yerman/PycharmProjects/genius/.buildozer/applibs jnius'
    # Cwd /home/yerman/PycharmProjects/genius/.buildozer
    DEPRECATION: --download-cache has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Pip now automatically uses and configures its cache.
    Collecting jnius
      Using cached jnius-1.0.2.tar.gz
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:


        You need Cython to compile Pyjnius.


        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
          File "/tmp/pip-build-_tfhLW/jnius/setup.py", line 32, in <module>
            from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
        ImportError: No module named Cython.Distutils

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_tfhLW/jnius
    # Command failed: pip install --download-cache=/home/yerman/.buildozer/cache --target=/home/yerman/PycharmProjects/genius/.buildozer/applibs jnius
    # 
    # Buildozer failed to execute the last command
    # The error might be hidden in the log above this error
    # Please read the full log, and search for it before
    # raising an issue with buildozer itself.
    # In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: The cython check is expected to fail (cython isn't installed in the python environment pyjnius is being installed to), but is wrapped in a try/except that should catch this. I'm not sure what's wrong.